# Error and issues while attempting to get PyQt5 to work with Pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, pyqt5

I want to use PyQt5 with pycharm,

I first did
`pip install PyQt5`
`pip install PyQt5-tools`
They installed correctly (I think)

But when trying to `import PyQt5` pycharm just says its unresolved.
I then attempted to goto Pycharm > settings > Project Interpeter > clicked the plus and attempted to install "PyQt5", it then stopped with an error, first it was I didn't have the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++, (which I did) but then I installed the microsoft visual build tools and attempted again, and now it comes up with a different error: 

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

and here is the command output:

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/eb/99720998026e8c021c269c175cc80590c98293e1006323c2de9a8741c19d/PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 (from PyQt5)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/fa/2c4c90bd328709129aae93a0bb15029982b6b5a3a2709679fca45bb7ee3b/PyQt5_sip-12.7.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt5-sip
  Building wheel for PyQt5-sip (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for PyQt5-sip (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py build_wheel C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqjlmpyqz:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'PyQt5.sip' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcapiversions.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\apiversions.obj
  apiversions.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcarray.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\array.obj
  array.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcdescriptors.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\descriptors.obj
  descriptors.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcint_convertors.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\int_convertors.obj
  int_convertors.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcobjmap.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\objmap.obj
  objmap.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcqtlib.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\qtlib.obj
  qtlib.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsiplib.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\siplib.obj
  siplib.c
  siplib.c(2902): warning C4013: 'sipSetBool' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcthreads.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\threads.obj
  threads.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcvoidptr.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\voidptr.obj
  voidptr.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\PointsCalculator\venv\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpbool.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\bool.obj
  bool.cpp
  c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'bool.cpp': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for PyQt5-sip
Failed to build PyQt5-sip

  Failed building wheel for PyQt5-sip
Could not build wheels for PyQt5-sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I'm not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error by going into the pycharm directory and finding the PyQt5 folder in the packages and deleted it, then copied the new PyQt5 package made by pip in the python package directory